# How to invoke extension method with parametrs

Tags: c#, select, extension-methods

i got the following extension methods:

```
    private RemarkItem GetRemarkItem(XElement xDataItem)
    {
        return new RemarkItem
        {
            RemarkType = RemarkType.Type1,
            Description = "bla bla" // temp
        };
    }

    private RemarkItem GetRemarkItem(XElement xDataItem, RemarkType type)
    {
        return new RemarkItem
        {
            RemarkType = type,
            Description = "bla bla" // temp
        };
    }
```

i know how to invoke the method with the single parameter:

```
IEnumerable<RemarkItem> remarkItems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
                        "./Root/Remarks/Remark").Select(GetRemarkItem);
```

but i dont know how to invoke the method with the 2 parameters...

any help would be appreciated

Comment: These are not extension methods. `public static ExtMethod(this XElement elem)` is extension method.

Comment: Please read first this, then ask... - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Your methods are not extension methods but `XPathSelectElements` is one. Maybe this helps: `xDoc.XPathSelectElements("./Root/Remarks/Remark").Select(ele => GetRemarkItem(ele, type));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'extension method' part aside, change your Select call to `x=>GetRemarkItem(x)`

```
IEnumerable<RemarkItem> remarkItems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
                    "./Root/Remarks/Remark")
                    .Select(node => GetRemarkItem(node));

IEnumerable<RemarkItem> remarkItems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
                    "./Root/Remarks/Remark")
                    .Select(node => GetRemarkItem(node, RemarkType.TypeA));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a correct implementation of extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static RemarkItem GetRemarkItem(this XElement xDataItem)
    {
        return new RemarkItem
        {
            RemarkType = RemarkType.Type1,
            Description = "bla bla" // temp
        };
    }

    public static RemarkItem GetRemarkItem(this XElement xDataItem, RemarkType type)
    {
        return new RemarkItem
        {
            RemarkType = type,
            Description = "bla bla" // temp
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can use them in this way:

```
IEnumerable<RemarkItem> remarkItems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
                    "./Root/Remarks/Remark").Select(GetRemarkItem);
```

or

```
    IEnumerable<RemarkItem> remarkItems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
                    "./Root/Remarks/Remark").Select(n => n.GetRemarkItem());
```

or

```
IEnumerable<RemarkItem> remarkItems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
                    "./Root/Remarks/Remark").Select(n => n.GetRemarkItem(RemarkType.Type1));
```

If you want to learn more about the extension methods please visit this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx